# Override default ActiveRecord generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to be able to override the default active record generators. I just want to override a few methods not replace the entire generator.

I have done this for the scaffold controllers using the following

```
class Rails::MyControllerGenerator < Rails::Generators::ScaffoldControllerGenerator
```

However using:

```
MyActiveRecordGenerator < ActiveRecord::Generators::ModelGenerator
```

Gives:

```
Error: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Generators::ModelGenerator.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is the correct incantation:

```
require 'rails/generators/active_record'
require 'rails/generators/active_record/model/model_generator'

class Rails::MyModelGenerator < ActiveRecord::Generators::ModelGenerator
```

You'll need to copy all the template files over as well as the Rails built in templates aren't included in the source_path